# Passive voice in the clause

Tags: word-usage

I am writing my personal statement and came across a question that I can not find an answer for. I am not sure if this sentence is correct:

> Despite the enormous 48 % annual increase in the amounts of medical
> data **generated**, rarely gets it translated into approved
> algorithms.

or this is better:

> Despite the enormous 48 % annual increase in the amounts of **generated** medical
> data, rarely gets it translated into approved
> algorithms.

Also, I am not sure if it is evident that by *it* I am referring to *medical data*.

I hope my question is clear. Thank you.

Comment: The biggest problem I see is in a different part of the sentence: "rarely gets it" should be "it rarely gets" - we don't do that word order inversion thing in English.

Comment: Despite the enormous 48 % annual increase in the amounts of generated medical data, rarely does the data get translated into approved algorithms

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SE! These questions are off topic for SE.Writing and I will have to vote to close it. To my knowledge, questions like this are supposed to be asked in English Language & Usage. That being said, I will answer your question as I'm sure it was written in good faith.

Comment: 'Despite the 48% (which is enormous) annual increase in the amounts of medical data generated, the data rarely gets translated into approved algorithms.' // This tidies (a little) the awkward dual prenominal string, and clarifies that it's the data in its entirety, not the 48% annual increase, that is being referenced. And 'medical data [which is] generated' is better than 'generated medical data' (as opposed to that which falls ready-made from trees?)

Comment: Is OP's question related to passive voice in the clause(s)?

Comment: @RamPillai Apparently it didn't come up in Writing. As far as the question as posed is concerned, a passive participial like _generated_ can either precede or follow its head noun; hence, **both** _the amounts of medical data generated_ and _the amounts of generated medical data_ are correct. And they both mean the same thing. Which one to use is the writer's choice. But watch out for that last clause.

Answer (score 0):

### ***Disclaimer:***

Hi, Welcome to SE! These questions are off topic for SE.Writing and I will have to vote to close it. To my knowledge, questions like this are supposed to be asked in English Language & Usage. That being said, I will answer your question as I'm sure it was written in good faith.

### ***Answer***

1. It should say "it rarely gets" instead of "rarely gets it."
2. Neither of the choices you have put works because the passive voice refers to the increase in data, not the data itself. A better was to write it is:

> "Despite its 48% annual increase in amount, generated medical data rarely gets translated into approved algorithms."

or

> "Despite its 48% annual increase in amount, medical data that is generated  rarely gets translated into approved algorithms."

Comment: Yes; the 'enormous 48%' string is unwieldy. But both factors are important. Also, 'medical data that is generated' at least hints at 'as opposed to the amount we get from elsewhere'.